# Python 3.7 simple_smartsheet, sheet.make_cell -> date error when uploading date and time to Smartsheet JSON Error Panda

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, smartsheet-api

**Getting JSON error: TypeError: Object of type time is not JSON serializable**

How do I make it so that I can include a date column in a row using **sheet.make_cell** command successfully? without the JSON error (above)?

1. Running Python 3.7
2. Imports:
   import logging

import csv

import os

import pandas as pd

from datetime import date

3. Read Excel file using Panda statement:

data = pd.read_excel('/home/pi/Documents/tscripts/Sample.xlsx',header = 0 )
df = pd.DataFrame(data)*

4. Output from **Panda** read **Excel** file command above:

*Excel file*:  *[[Timestamp('2020-09-05 09:08:00'), datetime.time(9, 8, 39), ' College_of_the_Desert_to_PDC_HUB', 30, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 'CCC-1494']]**

5. For loop to build a row.  The JSON error is at the **sheet.make_cell("MyDate", element[1])** statement.  Below is a copy/paste of the for loop.  All other sheet.make_cell commands are successful and added as a row to my Smartsheet.

**Row-column assignments in for loop where the JSON Error Occurs**
new_rows = []

for element in example:

```
row = Row(to_top=True,strong text

    cells=[

         sheet.make_cell("ccc_key_id", element[10]),

         sheet.make_cell("CCD", element[2]),

         sheet.make_cell("Max_In_Only", element[6]),

         sheet.make_cell("Max_Out_Only", element[9]),

         sheet.make_cell("avg_in_out_max", element[3]),

         sheet.make_cell("MyDate", element[1])  **<<== Result's in a JSON error ** 
    ])

new_rows.append(row)
```

smartsheet.sheets.add_rows(sheet.id, new_rows)

6. The MyDate column in Smartsheet can  be defined as Date or Text-Number, still results with a JSON error.

Looked up on the Internet and couldn't find anything to help.  Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the incorrect index number.  Should have been '0' instead of '1'. Grr.  Should have seen it.